# Таймер обратного отсчета на js

Tags: javascript

Нашел такой код таймера на js:

```
    const second = 1000,//ms
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Sep 30, 2019 00:00:00').getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

        document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
    }, second)
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему нельзя просто взять дату и отсчитывать от нее без использования `distance`? Еще я менял `math.floor` на `math.round` тогда совсем другие цифры были, как понять что использовать? И последний вопрос, почему там остаток берется `%`? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: _почему нельзя просто взять дату и отсчитывать от нее без использования distance?_ - почему нельзя?

Comment: _менял math.floor на math.round тогда совсем другие цифры_ - посмотри что делает [math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), а что [math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: _почему там остаток берется %_ - а что там должно браться вместо остатка?

Comment: @Grundy я использовал `math.round`, и там вместо `658` -> `659`, то есть почему именно `floor`. И про остаток я не понимаю, почему нельзя также делить, для чего его использовать? Спасибо.

Comment: Ты посмотрел что делает `math.floor`, а что `math.round`? Выше даны ссылки на описание этих функций.

Comment: _про остаток я не понимаю, почему нельзя также делить, для чего его использовать_ - ты знаешь чем отличается результат деления, от остатка от деления?

Comment: @Grundy да, я все посмотрел. да, знаю. upd: все понятно стало

Comment: Тогда напиши ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: На странице есть кнопка: "ответить на свой вопрос" - используй ее для добавления своего ответа, раз ты со всем разобрался